# Git remote commit disappear(related to standard input of git pre-receive hook)

Tags: git, gitlab

## Background

I am using gitlab. There is a [pre-receive](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-shell/blob/v2.7.2/hooks/pre-receive) hook in [gitlab-shell](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-shell) to check user permission of git push.

The pre-receive hook is written in ruby, and use `ARGF.read` to read the standard input of git, and will log it a file.

`<old-value> <new-value> <ref-name>`

In my development environment, the log looks like this:

```
sha-1  sha-2  ref/heads/master
sha-2  sha-3  ref/heads/master
sha-3  sha-4  ref/heads/master
....
```

When push to same branch, the **old-value** of this push is equal to the **new-value** of last push, accoring to the doc of [git-hooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks), this is reasonable.

## Problem

But in our production environment, something strange happen. The strange log looks like this:

```
[line 1 - MR1] sha-1  sha-2  ref/heads/master
[line 2 - MR2] sha-2  sha-3  ref/heads/master
[line 3 - MR3] sha-3  sha-4  ref/heads/master
[line 4 - MR4] sha-1(wrong!)  sha-5  ref/heads/master
...
```

Line 1 to line 4 were four merge operations on the gitlab web UI, and they were all successful merged according to the database record(I have check the merge_requests table and events table).

The problem is the *old-value* of MR4 become the *old-value* of MR1!

**The result is the commit of MR1, MR2, MR3 were all gone, just disappeared.**

## Troubleshooting

The only way I know can make the remote commit disappear is `force push`, but the master branch is protected (Gitlab can set protected_branch).

Anyway I try force push to a branch and the log looks like this:

```
sha-1  sha-2  ref/heads/master
sha-2  sha-3  ref/heads/master [force push]
sha-3  sha-4  ref/heads/master [force push]
....
```

The log is same as normal push.

Is this a bug of git? or gitlab? or rugged(gitlab use rugged to operate git repo)? or a normal git operate(How?)?

Comment: How about `git reset sha-1 --hard;git push origin -f master`?

Comment: I have try this, and also `rebase -i`, `commit --amend`